# MAC address of all unresponsive IPs in my network are the same as the gateway mac address

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address, arp

I have problems assigning a new address to one of my servers, every time I want to add a new address it says that the address is already in use. So what I'm doing now is to use the arp tool to see which ips are not in use.

What I've noticed that no matter how many different addresses I ping and I use arp afterward I get the same MAC address as the gateway. My question is first, is this a normal behavior? and second, how can I find an IP that is not in use then, any other ideas?

```
[user@swarm01 ~]$ ping 192.168.123.129
PING 192.168.123.129 (192.168.123.129) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.123.129 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1001ms

[user@swarm01 ~]$ arp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.123.126          ether   16:12:9c:31:73:fa   C                     eth0
192.168.123.59           ether   dc:a9:04:94:1e:c9   C                     eth0
192.168.123.129          ether   b4:0c:25:3f:e8:11   C                     eth0
192.168.123.128          ether   b4:0c:25:3f:e8:11   C                     eth0
192.168.123.127          ether   4c:66:41:2e:4e:9c   C                     eth0
gateway                  ether   b4:0c:25:3f:e8:11   C                     eth0
[user@swarm01 ~]$ ping 192.168.123.130
PING 192.168.123.130 (192.168.123.130) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.123.130 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2002ms

[user@swarm01 ~]$ arp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.123.126          ether   16:12:9c:31:73:fa   C                     eth0
192.168.123.59           ether   dc:a9:04:94:1e:c9   C                     eth0
192.168.123.129          ether   b4:0c:25:3f:e8:11   C                     eth0
192.168.123.130          ether   b4:0c:25:3f:e8:11   C                     eth0
192.168.123.128          ether   b4:0c:25:3f:e8:11   C                     eth0
192.168.123.127          ether   4c:66:41:2e:4e:9c   C                     eth0
gateway                  ether   b4:0c:25:3f:e8:11   C                     eth0
[user@swarm01 ~]$ ping 192.168.123.131
PING 192.168.123.131 (192.168.123.131) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.123.131 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3001ms

[user@swarm01 ~]$ arp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.123.131          ether   b4:0c:25:3f:e8:11   C                     eth0
192.168.123.126          ether   16:12:9c:31:73:fa   C                     eth0
192.168.123.59           ether   dc:a9:04:94:1e:c9   C                     eth0
192.168.123.129          ether   b4:0c:25:3f:e8:11   C                     eth0
192.168.123.130          ether   b4:0c:25:3f:e8:11   C                     eth0
192.168.123.128          ether   b4:0c:25:3f:e8:11   C                     eth0
192.168.123.127          ether   4c:66:41:2e:4e:9c   C                     eth0
gateway                  ether   b4:0c:25:3f:e8:11   C                     eth0
```

Comment: Is this your network? If so, do you know how its IP addressing was setup? What's the netmask? What's the IP address of the gateway? Is DHCP in use? What's the DHCP range if so?

Comment: Did you by chance set up Proxy Arp by accident? Its usually set up for sending packets across subnets, so unless you setup smaller networks, that probably isn't it, but that is the behavior you see with it.

Comment: @MaQleod Thank you for your comment, is Proxy Arp usually set up in the gateway or the DHCP server?

Comment: It is usually a separate feature in the router, it is not part of the WAN or LAN network settings or the DHCP conf. What router are you using?